# C# Sorting a List of an Object which contains another List of an Object

Tags: c#, list, sorting, object

Ok, I'm looking to sort the List (UserList) by the property (WordList), although I need (WordList) to be sorted by a particular property first.

The whole Sort UserList method does not sort the UserList whether I try by (userName) or by the (WordList).(wordName) or (WordList).(amountOfGuesses)

```
public class User
{
    public string userName;
    public List<Word> wordList;

    public User() { }

    public User(string name, String word, int guesses)
    {
        this.userName = name;
        wordList = new List<Word>();
        Word theWord = new Word(word, guesses);
        this.wordList.Add(theWord);
    }
}

public List<User> SortUserList(String g) 
    {
        String option = g.ToLowerInvariant();
        switch(option){
            case "name":
                this.UserList.OrderBy(x=> x.userName);
                break;
            case "word":
                this.UserList.OrderBy(k => k.wordList.OrderBy(w => w.wordName));
                break;
            case "guess":
                this.UserList.OrderBy(m=> m.wordList.OrderBy(y => y.amountOfGuesses));
                break;
        } 
        return UserList;
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        User xor = new User("xor", "xadfs", 20);
        User bob = new User("bob", "char", 3);
        User james = new User("james", "adfsad", 200);
        UserList.Add(bob);
        UserList.Add(james);
        UserList.Add(xor);
    }
```

Comment: How do you expect to sort *by* a list? What would the `wordList` values be for your example? Could you paste the definition of `User` (its constructors and properties)?

Comment: @Douglas
Pasted the Definition of User, and I want to sort UserList according to WordList already being sorted by a particular property

Comment: Will a user always only have just one word? If not, how would you sort when a user has several words? For example, if "xor" has "xadfs" and "aaa", whilst "bob" has just "char", how do you decide who comes first?

Comment: @Douglas Ooh I see the Issue here... So maybe I can approach it by first sorting the WordList by wordName in User, then get the First element of of WordList and sort the UserList that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort the users by their first word (in chronological order), you can use `Min` instead of your inner `OrderBy` on the `wordList` sequence.

Another issue you have with your code is that you assume that the outer `OrderBy` will update your source `UserList` sequence. It doesn't; rather, it leaves the source unchanged, and returns a new query that enumerates the ordered sequence. You can populate this by calling `ToList` and returning the result.

```
case "name":
    return this.UserList.OrderBy(x => x.userName).ToList();
case "word":
    return this.UserList.OrderBy(k => k.wordList.Min(w => w.wordName)).ToList();
case "guess":
    return this.UserList.OrderBy(m => m.wordList.Min(y => y.amountOfGuesses)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @Douglas my problems have been solved. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

If you need to order by the "top" element of a list, you can use [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to extract it:

```
UserList.OrderBy(k => k.wordList.OrderBy(w => w.wordName).FirstOrDefault());
```

I think this does what you want, I am not quite sure yet about what exactly you are asking though :-)

Comment: Yeah I'm going to need to take a similar approach as this, I have not tested this yet but something similar to this is what I'll have to do.

Comment: This will be inefficient. Never use a full sort when you only need the topmost element – it degrades your performance from O(n) to O(n log n).

Comment: @Douglas you are right, but don't make assumptions on efficiency or the implementation for operators. In most cases, it's likely irrelevant, anyways.

Comment: @Sklivvz: These asymptotic complexities are well-known; I'm not making any assumptions. A LINQ provider might be smart enough to merge the `OrderBy().First()` into a `Min()`, but *that* is the kind of assumption one should not make. And it won't be irrelevant unless the OP is coding toy systems.

Comment: I didn't say otherwise. Knowing the asymptotic behavior of an algorithm does not have any bearing on the practical non-asymptotic behavior, where other factors are much more relevant than the number of items. My point is: you are assuming the numbers are large, and this is unwarranted without more info :-)

Comment: Thanks @Sklivvz your solutions have helped me solve my issues. I really appreciate the help !!

Comment: @Sklivvz: Yes, I did assume that the numbers would get large. If they don't, then you're right in saying that the performance difference will be likely irrelevant.